# Error consulta SQL-ODBC-FIREBIRD

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, firebird

¿Sabrán cual sera el error, para este pequeño update que estoy haciendo desde SQL Server 2019, para una ODBC de Firebird?

```
El proveedor OLE DB 'MSDASQL' del servidor vinculado 'Nombre de la ODBC' devolvió el mensaje '[ODBC Firebird Driver]COUNT field incorrect'.
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 3
El proveedor OLE DB 'MSDASQL' del servidor vinculado 'Nombre de la ODBC' no pudo UPDATE la tabla '[MSDASQL]'.
```

La consulta es

```
update openquery 
(odbc,'select pedido,tipo from pedido where pedido in(133334,133320,133308)')
set tipo= 1
```

Mi servidor es Windows server 2019.

Tengo otro servidor 2016 con la misma ODBC y mi SQL es 2016 y realizo el mismo update y lo ejecuta sin problemas

No me deja ejecutar la consulta en el server 2019 sql 2019
pero  en el server 2016 si

Al ejecutar FbProfile me arrojo esta información

Revise el Profile y me mandó a la hora de mandar el update de regreso a Firebird

```
2024-03-13T13:42:13.1460 
(31311:0x7f09e0e0ef50) 
PREPARE_STATEMENT 
/usr/local/base.gdb
 (ATT_517, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xxx.xx.xx) 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL15.F\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:5216 
(TRA_116950, READ_COMMITTED | REC_VERSION | WAIT | READ_WRITE) Statement 58: UPDATE PEDIDO SET TIPO=? WHERE (PEDIDO=? AND TIPO=? ) 

 PLAN (PEDIDO INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY592)) 2 ms 

Es el primero
2024-03-13T17:55:36.4660 (61135:0x7fee97ffbef8) ATTACH_DATABASE
    /usr/local/base.gdb (ATT_521, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xx.xx.xx)
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.FIL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:13644

Es el segundo 
2024-03-13T17:55:36.4690 (61135:0x7fee97ffbef8) START_TRANSACTION
    /usr/local/base.gdb (ATT_521, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xx.xx.xx)
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.FIL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:13644
        (TRA_116960, READ_COMMITTED | REC_VERSION | WAIT | READ_WRITE)

Es el tercero
2024-03-13T17:55:36.4770 (61135:0x7fee97ffbef8) PREPARE_STATEMENT
    /usr/local/base.gdb (ATT_521, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xx.xx.xx)
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.FILL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:13644
        (TRA_116960, READ_COMMITTED | REC_VERSION | WAIT | READ_WRITE)

Statement 53:

SELECT PEDIDO,TIPO FROM PEDIDOS WHERE PEDIDO IN (38,33,25)

PLAN (PEDIDO INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592))

El cuarto 
2024-03-13T17:55:36.4830 (61135:0x7fee97ffbef8) FREE_STATEMENT
    /usr/local/base.gdb (ATT_521, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xx.xx.xx)
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.FIL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:13644

Statement 53:

SELECT PEDIDO,TIPO FROM PEDIDOS WHERE PEDIDO IN (38,33,25)

PLAN (PEDIDO INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592))

El Quinto 
2024-03-13T17:55:36.4840 (61135:0x7fee97ffbef8) PREPARE_STATEMENT
    /usr/local/base.gdb (ATT_521, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xx.xx.xx)
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.FIL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:13644
        (TRA_116960, READ_COMMITTED | REC_VERSION | WAIT | READ_WRITE)

Statement 56:

SELECT PEDIDO,TIPO FROM PEDIDO WHERE PEDIDO IN (38,33,25)

PLAN (PEDIDO INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592))

El sexto
2024-03-13T17:55:36.4850 (61135:0x7fee97ffbef8) EXECUTE_STATEMENT_START
    /usr/local/base.gdb (ATT_521, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xx.xx.xx)
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.FIL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:13644
        (TRA_116960, READ_COMMITTED | REC_VERSION | WAIT | READ_WRITE)

Statement 56:

SELECT PEDIDO,TIPO FROM PEDIDO WHERE PEDIDO IN (38,33,25)

PLAN (PEDIDO INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592))

El septimo
2024-03-13T17:55:36.4860 (61135:0x7fee97ffbef8) EXECUTE_STATEMENT_FINISH
    /usr/local/base.gdb (ATT_521, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xx.xx.xx)
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.FIL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:13644
        (TRA_116960, READ_COMMITTED | REC_VERSION | WAIT | READ_WRITE)

Statement 56:

SELECT PEDIDO,TIPO FROM PEDIDOS WHERE PEDIDO IN (38,33,25)

PLAN (PEDIDO INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592, RDB$PRIMARY592))
3 records fetched
      0 ms, 1 read(s), 12 fetch(es)

Table                             Natural     Index    Update    Insert    Delete   Backout     Purge   Expunge
***************************************************************************************************************
PEDIDO   

El octavo
2024-03-13T17:55:36.4930 (61135:0x7fee97ffbef8) PREPARE_STATEMENT
    /usr/local/base.gdb (ATT_521, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xx.xx.xx)
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.FIL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:13644
        (TRA_116960, READ_COMMITTED | REC_VERSION | WAIT | READ_WRITE)

Statement 57:
UPDATE PEDIDO SET TIPO=? WHERE (PEDIDO=? AND TIPO=? )

PLAN (PEDIDO INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY592))
      2 ms 

                                   3
```

Hasta alli es donde me manda datos y ya no me da resultados

Comment: ¿Cuál es la llave primaria de la tabla pedido en Firebird?

Comment: La llave Primaria es pedido

Comment: Qué versión de FB estás usando? Si es 2.5 o superior, puedes valerte de la TraceAPI y herramientas como FBProfiler para ver qué consultas están llegando al servidor y cuál es la que falla. Por lo que estuve leyendo, este error ocurre cuándo no hay coincidencia entre el número de parámetros en el texto de una consulta y los asignados, pero esto lo está haciendo el SQL Server tras bambalinas, así que es difícil decir. Si estuviera mal, una posible solución es lanzar vos directamente el update hacia Firebird.

Comment: La versión que estoy usando es 2.5..

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que revela el profiler?

Comment: UPDATE PEDIDOS SET TIPO=? WHERE (PEDIDO=? AND TIPO=? ) Revise el Profile y me mando a la hora de mandar el update de regreso a Firebird

Comment: 2024-03-13T13:42:13.1460 (31311:0x7f09e0e0ef50) PREPARE_STATEMENT
 /usr/local/base.gdb (ATT_517, SYSDBA:NONE, NONE, TCPv4:xxx.xxx.xx.xx)
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.F\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe:5216
  (TRA_116950, READ_COMMITTED | REC_VERSION | WAIT | READ_WRITE)

Statement 58:

UPDATE PEDIDO SET TIPO=? WHERE (PEDIDO=? AND TIPO=? )
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PLAN (PEDIDO INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY592))
      2 ms

Comment: Es mejor que edites la pregunta y agregues allí esa información, en comentarios es muy difícil leerlo. Saludos.

Comment: Esperaría ver en algún lugar los valores establecidos para los parámetros. Vemos claramente que forma una sentencia con 3 de estos, pero, cuántos envía?

Comment: No lista los parámetros. Buscando alternativas, has considerado la opción de utilizar `exec` en lugar de `openquery`, tengo entendido que debiera funcionar si haces `exec('update pedido set tipo = 1 where pedido in (1, 2, 3)') AT [odbc]`

Comment: Perfecto!!!!!! asi me deja, tendre que modificar la mayoria de mi codigo, ¿no existira una alternativa para no tener que modficar todas mis querys?

Comment: Marcelo, diría que si debe haber alternativa, pero hasta no entender bien lo que está fallando, hasta ahora solo se me ocurre esa forma de pasarle por un costado. Y sospecho que el bug o lo que haya que hacer, va a estar del lado de SQL Server y no de Firebird.

Comment: Dado que funcionó, publiqué la alternativa como una respuesta, esperando que pueda ser de utilidad para alguien más que se tope con el problema y  no se quede perdida en comentarios. Un saludo y me alegra haber sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base a la información recolectada y publicada, no puedo identificar el origen del problema.

Puedo comentar que el error:

> ```
> [ODBC Firebird Driver]COUNT field incorrect
> ```

Según mi investigación, se da cuando no coincide el número de parámetros establecidos en una consulta, con el número de parámetros proporcionados para ejecutarla.

## Workaround

Sin embargo, como solución alterna, propongo que lances el `update` para que sea ejecutado directamente del lado de Firebird y no por SQL Server.

Esto se podría hacer con una sentencia como esta:

```sql
exec('update pedido set tipo = 1 where pedido in (133334,133320,133308)') AT [odbc]
```

Esta sentencia, como he mencionado antes, tiene la *ventaja* que no será interpretada por SQL Server, sino será transmitida tal cual a Firebird, que realizará la acción solicitada directamente.

Sé que esto puede implicar cambios en la programación que ya tienes pero, por ahora, parece viable hasta que se encuentre la causa/solución del error que te está presentando.